# Edittext Validation error message in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

In my app i usually show validation error msg like follow :

```
 if(someString.equals("")){
     editText.setError("UserName Should not be blank");
 }
```

is there other way to show error message??

i need your suggestion

Comment: editText does not have any setError method!!!! do you use any library?!!!!

Comment: you can check doc  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: Use Toast to display Error message.

Comment: @Hardik Of course it has. It is inherited from TextView

Comment: @Hardik i dont use any library. there is a option to popover the error msg in editText

Comment: @Lucifer display toast msg will not be good for user.. i need some efficient way open popover or popup

Comment: see here  http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/android-validator-form-validator-library/

Comment: @AristoMichael then try AlertDialog, It remain on the screen until user presses any button to close the AlertDialog.

Comment: Use [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: Suppose i open the alert how can i highlight mandatory fields?

Answer (score 15):

I think the way you are showing the error message is better than toast. Sometimes toast duration is too short and the user isn't able to see that.

You can also achieve it by doing this:

```
EditText et11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
if(et11.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
    et11.setError("UserName Should not be blank");
}
```

Comment: i tried this but the customer want some other efficient way to alert notification

Comment: So i think you must have show all the three notification methods to client for android.Alert Dialogs,Toasts,Notifications.Because clients choice matters in this case.Then implement any method what he suggested/wants :)

Comment: Is there any way to highlight only mandatory fields to customer to fill suppose if they leave that fields null?

Comment: yeah you can do this.Hide the unnecessary fields from the user.and shows only mandatory fields.
 Editext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Also please check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106121/android-how-to-highlight-edittext-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
private EditText edt_firstName;
private String firstName;
 firstName = edt_firstName.getText().toString().trim();

private void validateData(){
firstName = edt_firstName.getText().toString().trim();
if (!firstName.isEmpty(){
//here api call for the login or any other...
} else {
            if (firstName.isEmpty()) {
                edt_firstName.setError("Please Enter First Name");
                edt_firstName.requestFocus();
            }
}
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).